# How to log application logs using AWS Log Driver to different log groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an application where I want to keep track of three type of logs.

1. Audit
2. Trace
3. System

I am sending this logs using `AWS Log Driver` to `Cloud Watch Logs`.

Below is the pseudo code.

```
If(Audit Logs)
{
    foreach(var audit in AuditLogs)
    {
        console.writeline(audit);
    }
}
If(Trace Logs)
{
    foreach(var trace in TraceLogs)
    {
        console.writeline(trace);
    }
}
If(System Logs)
{
    foreach(var system in SystemLogs)
    {
        console.writeline(system);
    }
}
```

Below is the `task.Json` configuration for sending logs to the `Cloud Watch Logs`:

```
"logConfiguration": {
    "logDriver": "awslogs",
    "options": {
      "awslogs-group": "lt-stg-secops",
      "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
      "awslogs-stream-prefix": "transactions-stg-secops"
    }
  }
```

**Question:** Now with above configuration all the logs are going to `same log group`. Is there any way I can direct all three logs to go to separate log groups.

Comment: Repeating the same question is likely to cause people to downvote you. I've marked your other question as a duplicate of this one, but recommend that you delete it.

Comment: I don't have time to answer, but the short answer is that you need to be using the awslogs agent, rather than the driver. The driver simply redirects stdout/stderr to the log destination, while the agent reads from one or more files. Of course, that means that you need to write your logs to files, which may require a code change.

Comment: Alternatively, depending on your language you might find a logging framework that lets you direct logs to different destinations.